# C#. How to deserialize complex JSON to some object?

Tags: c#, json

I use pinterest API to get some info, for example 
[pinterest API link](https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/Monokumagirl/anime-girls/pins/)

As you see, this link returns text in JSON format, and it's pretty complex, so simple

```
Dictionary<string,string>
```

unsuitable I guess.

What solution you can recommend to solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an external API like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and either deserialize to a POCO object that you create or a JObject (Json.NET is still in the top3 of the most downloaded package on Nuget, no worries, it's here to stay).

The first would ensure that the data is conform out of the box, but forces you to declare the data class beforehand. From the official doc of Json.NET

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

The second is a kind of dynamic object that "accepts" any kind of data an let you pull from it at runtime (more dangerous, but tremendously more flexible).

```
JArray array = new JArray();
array.Add("Manual text");
array.Add(new DateTime(2000, 5, 23));

JObject o = new JObject();
o["MyArray"] = array;

string json = o.ToString();
// {
//   "MyArray": [
//     "Manual text",
//     "2000-05-23T00:00:00"
//   ]
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class structure as per JSON response

For example,

```
public class Pinner
{
    public string about { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public int follower_count { get; set; }
    public string image_small_url { get; set; }
    public int pin_count { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string profile_url { get; set; }
}


public class Pin
{
    public object attribution { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Pinner pinner { get; set; }
    public int repin_count { get; set; }
    public string dominant_color { get; set; }
    public int like_count { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public Embed embed { get; set; }
    public bool is_video { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string about { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public int follower_count { get; set; }
    public string image_small_url { get; set; }
    public int pin_count { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string profile_url { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Pin> pins { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Board board { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public string generated_at { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Use JavaScriptSerializer ,

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<RootObject>(Your JSon String);
```

Comment: How to be with 237x ? I can create a class which name starts with a number

Answer (score 0):

1. Create classes acording to your JSON object. I suggest you to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), it helps you to generate your classes easily.
2. Use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization and deserialization. In this [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) you can find more information about it.

Comment: I got __invalid_type__237x for "237x" object and I guess this will not works

Comment: It could be possible, remember that it is a generic tool, so you can have problems at certain cases. Try another ones like http://jsonutils.com/ and https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/ Finally you can try to remove the fields with the trouble and then add it manually to your resulting classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I did what I wanted using this code

```
 public Program()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string str = client.DownloadString("https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/Monokumagirl/anime-girls/pins/");

                JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(str);

                JToken pins = jobject["data"]["pins"];

                int i = 0;
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        var pin = pins[i];
                        Console.WriteLine(pin["images"]["237x"]["url"]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("count: " + i);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```